# How to reject binary from iTunes store (new iTunes Connect website)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Apple introduced the new iTunes Connect website.

I am trying to reject the binary file and re-upload a new one. However, when I read the documentation `To remove your build from review`, it shows me:

[image]

however, in mine is showing something like below:

status:

[image]

[image]

I don't see a 'remove this version from review' link. How to get the page like the one in the doc?

Comment: Logout of ITC and log back in. Then return to the page where you should see the link. The new website is really screwed up if your login session has timed out. Some of it works but some of it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now need to be at least an `App Manager` or higher to reject the binary. You cannot do this as a `Developer`.

Try to logout login back. Under Versions tab select your new uploaded version. Link should appear.